# Why the CSS property in later keyframe get applied earlier than expected in CSS animations?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, css-position

Let me share  pictures what I am trying to achieve, that will be more efficient, I guess:
[image]

Here small box with pink center is #d1 and it's parent #dn has a center red.
My objective is to co-center the pink with red. I know there are also other centering techniques like flex box, margin 0 auto but I am focusing on translate for now.

First stage: position the absolute #d1 with top 50% and left 50%. Here I haven't included any margin for #d1.
[image: Result after position offset values]
Now I tried using hover but I want multi stages changes so I  opted to animation, in second stage I used translate:(-50%,-50%) to co-center the pink with red center. I am still confused whether to use transform:translate() or translate: . Anyways, this is the expected result
[image: Result after translate]
Now you can go through the code, you can directly jump to animation `@keyframes` , because that is what troubling me.

```css
#dn{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: #15badb;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    /* display flex for centering of dot plus #d1 ni hunxa*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.dot{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #9e1818;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: border-radius 5s;
}

#d1{
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255, 233,0);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* Initially I dont want #d1 to be flex centered so i applied top bottom absolute */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 18s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes example{
  0%{ top: 0%; left:0%; transform: translate(0%, 0%);}
  50%{top: 50%; left:50%; transform: translate(0%, 0%);}
  80%{top: 50%; left:50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

  /* 100%{top: 0%; left:0%;} */
}

/* Separate color for dot inside #d1 */
#d1 .dot{
    background-color: #f07fba;
}
```

```html
<div id="dn">
    <div id="d1">
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Here I am compelled to write `transform: translate(0%, 0%); at  keyframes 0% and 50%`, however my initial intuitive code was this

```css
@keyframes example{
    0%{ top: 0%; left:0%; }
    50%{top: 50%; left:50%; }
    80%{ transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
   
    /* 100%{top: 0%; left:0%;} */
}
```

why the code is not running as per my objective?

Comment: Why are you manipulating both the translate _and_ top/left in your animation? It should only be the former.

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems to work, and I'm not totally clear on what the problem is.  You had 3 steps in your animation and each one happened.  However if you simplify it to just

```css
@keyframes example{
  0%{ top: 0%; left:0%; transform: translate(0, 0);}
  50%{top: 50%; left:50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
}
```

Then it will move smoothly from the top left corner to the dot in the center. Is this what you want?

```css
#dn{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: #15badb;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    /* display flex for centering of dot plus #d1 ni hunxa*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.dot{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #9e1818;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: border-radius 5s;
}

#d1{
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255, 233,0);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* Initially I dont want #d1 to be flex centered so i applied top bottom absolute */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 18s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes example{
  0%{ top: 0%; left:0%; transform: translate(0, 0);}
  50%{top: 50%; left:50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

  /* 100%{top: 0%; left:0%;} */
}

/* Separate color for dot inside #d1 */
#d1 .dot{
    background-color: #f07fba;
}
```

```html
<div id="dn">
    <div id="d1">
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do, I suggest you to run my code snippet. You can see two stages, at first stage pink center approaches near to the red center but goes away but at second stage it travels back and co center with red and after end of animation pink dot returns back to its initial position.

Comment: So you are saying your animation is what you want, but you just don't want it to return to the start position?